# How to push a key-value pair onto a MongoDB object?

Tags: mongodb

At the moment I am attempting to push a key:value pair onto this "graphs" object in mongo at the next key index. For example, If I wanted to push `{ "type": "stuff", "module": "Salty Dogs" }` if would append that to the below structure at key `"2":`

```
        "_id" : ObjectId("654a56ds4f56asdf"),
        "graphs" : {
                "0" : {
                        "type" : "graphy",
                        "module" : "movement"
                },
                "1" : {
                        "type" : "sans fiber",
                        "module" : "FIBER"
                }
        }
```

I have tried using `db.collection.update({"uuid" => @uuid}, "$push" =>{"graphs" =>  {"type" => type, "module" => module}})` but was unsuccessful because in order to use that it needs to be an array. SO I was just wondering if anyone could help me push an key:value pair onto this object.